# How to Dispose VlcControl for wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, vlc

I am using Vlc.DotNet.Wpf for playing video

1. creating VlcControl object

`

```
private void CreateVlcObject1()
{
   myControl1 = new VlcControl();
   myControl1.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectoryNeeded+=MediaPlayer_VlcLibDirectoryNeeded;
   myControl1.MediaPlayer.EndReached += MediaPlayer_EndReached1;    
   myControl1.MediaPlayer.EndInit(); myControl1.MediaPlayer.Play(newUri(@"C:\Users\Public\videos\45.mp4"));
   MainGrid.Children.Add(myControl1);
}
```

`

2. Dispose Method of VlcControl object

`

```
  private void DisposeObject1()
  {  
    myControl1.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectoryNeeded -=   MediaPlayer_VlcLibDirectoryNeeded1;
    myControl1.MediaPlayer.EndReached -= MediaPlayer_EndReached1;


    if (!myControl1.MediaPlayer.IsDisposed)
    {
       myControl1.MediaPlayer.Stop();                
       myControl1.MediaPlayer.Dispose();
    }
       myControl1 = null;
       MainGrid.Children.Remove(myControl1);
 }
```

`

the program get stuck at stop method in Dispose method however if i comment stop method it will stuck at the dispose method.
Without Disposing this object i can't proceed further as it eats 100 MB in 1 min.

When I break it shows like this:
[image: Break All]
My Question is how to Dispose this VlcControl object
**Edited**
I am disposing vlc object in every 15 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I found this link:

http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2008/06/23/dispose-of-a-wpf-usercontrol-ish.aspx

I think the  `Dispatcher.ShutdownStarted += Dispatcher_ShutdownStarted;` is the correct way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @WolfgangThanks for your reply i dont want to close application so i think shutdownStarted event is no use to me.

Comment: I found on the Github Forum, that you should do a Application.DoEvents(); befor stop:
this.vlcControl.Stop();

Answer (score 1):

Vlc.DotNet is currently very sensitive when using callbacks : you need to make sure that you are calling Dispose() and other Vlc-related methods from the same thread that was creating the control.

If you are using Timers to Dispose the control, as you said in your question, chances are that there are more than one thread involved.

In Wpf, I'd say a good choice is using `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => {...});`

Thanks for using Vlc.DotNet

Comment: I'm not the one that created it, I'm the one who maintains it ;)

Answer (score -2):

Before Disposing MediaPlayer await for MediaPlayer to stop, Here you can do it like this

```
>  await MediaPlayer.StopAsync(); //Used in .Net4.5 and above
> 
>  MediaPlayer.Dispose();
```

Comment: there is no StopASync() method.

Comment: Check this two links might be helpful for you http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/workitem/6496 https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109639/nVLC?msg=3971279#xx3971279xx

Comment: This is *not* for VLC controls